# how to iterate through the selectors with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Suppose, I have multiple selectors used

```
$('.some, .next, .any, .way, .myname, .something')
```

and now if I would like to change each background when one background is changed, so I'm wondering how can I iterate all selectors using likely to this: `$(this).each()` but I know this will not work coz this will take currently selected each elements but I would like to do all the selectors in my selectors used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to do it :

```
var o = $('.some, .next, .any, .way, .myname, .something');
$.each(o.selector.split(/,\s*/), function(s){
    var os = o.filter(s); // or $(s)
    ...
});
```

Not that this simple solution wouldn't work for any selector, a parsing would be needed if you really want to support them all (but it's probable you don't have commas in your elements id ;) ).

Comment: n can u explain about filter(s) , i din't understand that...!

Comment: In the loop, `s` is a simple selector. You may indifferently use `$(s)` or `o.filter(s)`. In case of simple selectors based on classes or id, `$(s)` would be faster. If the selectors are heavy and the elements few, using `o.filter(s)` would avoid a global search, by looking only in `o`.